# Concentration of a drug by its derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives, polynomials

The concentration C (in mg / L) of a drug in the blood t minutes after it is administered is represented by the function $C(t)=- 0.016t^2 + 2.32t$.

Calculate the drug withdrawal during the 100th minute.

Method 1:
$D C(100) = -0.88$

Method 2: Check

$C(99) - C(100) = 72-72.864 = 0.864$

Why is the outcome of method 1 is not the same as method 2?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative $C^{\prime}$ at $t=100$ is defined as the limit
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{C(100+h)-C(100)}{h}.$$

Therefore, what you do in Method 2 is making an approximation to $-C^{\prime}(99)$ by setting $h=1$. This is not far away from $-C^{\prime}(100)$ in this case, but not the same. Geometrically speaking, in Method 1 you calculate the slope of the tangent line at $C(100)$ whereas in Method 2 you calculate the slope of a secant through $C(99)$ and $C(100)$.

Comment: Method 2 is more correct to calculate the change within the 100th minute, or am I wrong? Why do you say that method 2 is an approximation to ′(99)? Isn't it an approximation to C'(100)?

Comment: As the question, as I interpret it, asks for the change within a time interval (1 minute) and not the change at a point in time, I think indeed that method 2 would be the adequate choice here.

Comment: If you look at the definition of the derivative, you see that $C(100)-C(99) = \frac{C(99+h)-C(99)}{h}$ for $h=1$ is an approximation to $C^{\prime}(99)$.

Comment: So to approximation C'(100) I have to calculate C(101) -C(100)? Why?

Comment: Both are valid approximations, but from different sides. If $h$ approaches zero, they will become the same.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of a function is the rate of change of the value of the function $\mathit at\space that \space point.$

In your case, the derivative at t = 100 is the rate at which drug is being withdrawn precisely at t = 100.0 mins.
Note that this rate changes as t changes from 99 min to 100 min.

$$R_{ate}(t) = -{d \over dt}C(t)$$

Summing up this rate w.r.t time over interval $(99, 100]$, i.e. total drug withdrawn during the $100^{th}$ minute will be: $$-\int_{99}^{100} R_{ate}(t)dt = C(99) - C(100)$$
Since, $-C(t)$ is the anti-derivate of $R_{ate}(t).$